# How to determine if usage data is out of the ordinary given all the different ways to slice up a time stamp?

Tags: time-series, outliers, anomaly-detection

I am attempting to find abnormal usage patterns in a billing system.

Usage looks like this:

```
ID    Datetime     Quantity
A     2016-01-01   10
A     2016-01-01   50
A     2016-01-02   20
A     2016-01-02   40
```

Usage has some pretty standard characteristics. It is high during the weekdays, and falls during the weekends. On holidays it falls. Fridays are a tad lower than Thursdays. Therefor, I cannot just calculate the average and standard deviation without slicing up the timestamp to account for these changes.

I have split the timestamp into the following metrics:

- Month
- Day of Month
- Day of Week
- Week
- Is Holiday

E.g.,

```
id  month  day_of_month week day_of_week is_holiday  quantity
A   Jan    1            1    Monday      false       10
A   Jan    1            1    Monday      True        50
```

Alternatively, I could simply use two metrics: `is_weekend` and `is_holiday`.

I've then computed the average and standard deviation across all these metrics for each ID since the beginning of time.

So let's take the following scenario: Today is a Monday, in the 7th week of the year, in the 2nd month of the year, on the 4th day of the month, and it is not a holiday. I've already computed the following for these metrics:

```
Metric           Avg   Stddev
Monday           2500  800
Not Holiday      2000  1000
7th week         2200  600
2nd month        2400  300
4th day of month 1900  800
```

Is there any way to take these numbers and compute a "target average" of 2245.5 and "target stddev" of 758.2, to which I can compare against today's usage?

Otherwise, I could use the following rules, for example:

- If the usage falls outside a stddev for just one metric, flag it as abnormal
- If the usage falls outside of a stddev for ALL metrics, flag it as abnormal

Is there a standard way of detecting anomalies given all the ways I can slice a timestamp?